# Azure Data Factory Lookup Source Data and Mail Notification

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I am trying my best to solve following scenario.
I am using PowerShell scripts to collect some information about my server environments and saving like .csv files. 
There are information about Hardware, Running Services etc. in the .csv files.
I am sending these .csv files into Blob Storage and using Azure Data Factory V2 Pipelines to write these information into Azure SQL. I have succesfully configured mail notification via Azure Logic Apps that is informing me the Pipeline Run was succesfull/unsuccesfull.
Now I am trying to lookup into source data to find concrete column. In my scenario it is column with the name of Windows Service - for example - Column: PrintSpooler - Row: Running.
So I need to lookup for concretely column and also send a mail notification if the service is running or it is stopped.
Is there any way how to do that ? 
In ideal way I want to receive a mail only in case the Service in my Source Data is stopped.
Thank you for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Do you update the .csv file or upload a new .csv file?

If you upload a new .csv, then you can use azure function blob trigger.

This trigger will collect the new upload blob and you can do process on this blob. You can get the data in the .csv file and create an alert to your email.

This is the offcial document of azure function timetrigger:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function

In the blobtrigger, you can search whether there is a value in the .csv file and then you can set an output binding.

And then, go to this place:

[image]

[image]

Then you will get the alert in your email when the data in csv file is meet your requirement.